# C++/OpenGL/SFML Vertex Coloring

Tags: c++, opengl, colors, sfml, vertex

I have recently been learning about [vertex coloring](http://www.swiftless.com/tutorials/opengl/vertex_colors.html). The program worked fine when I used just glut/OpenGL. However, I want to use SFML for application, so I tried changing the code found on [this site](http://www.swiftless.com/tutorials/opengl/vertex_colors.html) to something SFML could use. However, only a solid color for the entire quad works; per vertex coloring produces only a white square. Below is a small, minimal example that reproduces my problem:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <gl/gl.h>
#include <gl/glu.h>

class Scene {
public:
    void resize( int w, int h ) {
        // OpenGL Reshape
        glViewport( 0, 0, w, h );
        glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
        glLoadIdentity();
        gluPerspective( 120.0, (GLdouble)w/(GLdouble)h, 0.5, 500.0 );
        glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
    }
};

int main() {

    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600, 32), "Test");

    ///Setup the scene, materials, lighting
    Scene scene;
    scene.resize(800,600);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glColorMaterial(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_EMISSION);
    glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
    glShadeModel(GL_FLAT);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
    float XL = .5, YL = .1, ZL = 1;
    GLfloat ambientLight[] = { 0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1.0f };
    GLfloat diffuseLight[] = { 0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8, 1.0f };
    GLfloat specularLight[] = { 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f };
    GLfloat lightpos[] = {XL, YL, ZL, 0.};
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, ambientLight);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, diffuseLight);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPECULAR, specularLight);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, lightpos);

    ///Start loop
    while( window.isOpen() ) {
        sf::Event event;
        while( window.pollEvent( event ) ) {
            if( event.type == sf::Event::Closed )
                window.close();
        }

        glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        gluPerspective(50.0, 1.0, 1.0, 50);
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glLoadIdentity();
        gluLookAt(1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0);

        glColor3f(1, 0, 0);

        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
           // glColor3f(1,0,0); //red
            glVertex3f(-0.5, -0.5, 0.0);
           // glColor3f(0,1,0); //green
            glVertex3f(-0.5, 0.5, 0.0);
           // glColor3f(0,0,1); //blue
            glVertex3f(0.5, 0.5, 0.0);
           // glColor3f(1,1,1); //white
            glVertex3f(0.5, -0.5, 0.0);
        glEnd();

        ///Reset env settings for SFML
        glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);

        window.display();
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Are those glColor3f's commented out for a reason?

Comment: They are there to represent where the glColor3fs should be. Un-commenting them results in a completely white square, which should not be the case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you have turned on flat shading, which disables color interpolation between vertices.

Remove the glShadeModel call, or replace it with `glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH)` (the default).

> GL primitives can have either flat or smooth shading.
>               Smooth shading,
>               the default,
>               causes the computed colors of vertices to be interpolated as the
>               primitive is rasterized,
>               typically assigning different colors to each resulting pixel fragment.
>               Flat shading selects the computed color of just one vertex
>               and assigns it to all the pixel fragments
>               generated by rasterizing a single primitive.
>               In either case, the computed color of a vertex is the result of
>               lighting if lighting is enabled,
>               or it is the current color at the time the vertex was specified if
>               lighting is disabled.